# Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver];Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exceptionhandler, handlerexceptionresolver

My **GlobalExceptionHandlerController** class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerController {

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public String handleError404(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        return "404";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public String handleError400(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        return "errors1";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    public String handleError403(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        return "errors2";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public String handleError500(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        return "errors3";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS)
    public String handleError429(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        return "errors4";
    }

}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class java.lang.Exception]: {public java.lang.String com.fussa.fyby.configuration.GlobalExceptionHandlerController.handleError403(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.Exception), public java.lang.String com.fussa.fyby.configuration.GlobalExceptionHandlerController.handleError400(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.Exception)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class java.lang.Exception]: {public java.lang.String com.fussa.fyby.configuration.GlobalExceptionHandlerController.handleError403(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.Exception), public java.lang.String com.fussa.fyby.configuration.GlobalExceptionHandlerController.handleError400(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.Exception)}
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.addExceptionMapping(ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.<init>(ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.initExceptionHandlerAdviceCache(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:265)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.afterPropertiesSet(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:241)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.handlerExceptionResolver(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:822)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$400a1941.CGLIB$handlerExceptionResolver$41(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$400a1941$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2aaff7a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$400a1941.handlerExceptionResolver(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 25 more
```

Thanks for any advices..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring can not guess which handler method it should use for which exception. Since you don't define them.

Set the value for the ExceptionHandler annotation for each method appropriate and make sure there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

As [mh-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193305/failed-to-instantiate-org-springframework-web-servlet-handlerexceptionresolver/40193367#40193367) suggest, i defined exception for each ExceptionHandler annotation:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerController {

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public String handleError404(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        return "404";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({ HttpClientErrorException.class,Throwable.class  })
    @ResponseStatus
    public String handleError4xx(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        return "errors4";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpServerErrorException.class)
    @ResponseStatus
    public String handleError5xx(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        return "errors5";
    }

}
```